# Why is my For Each loop not looping through all worksheets in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, worksheet

I'm trying to loop a bunch of code through all worksheets in a workbook. However it is only applying to the sheet I am on when I trigger the macro. I think that this *may* be caused by the fact that I am activating cells (which I understand is a no-no but don't fully understand how to avoid) ultimately however I am unsure of the cause.

The code I am running is entered below. It is only one part of a larger macro. the parts which follow this are working fine but do not necessitate looping through all sheets and inputting values into them. I'm relatively new to this, so any advice that might be helpful would be very welcome.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

  

            ' Input Lookup values into Column S
        Range("S19").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S20").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S21").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S22").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S23").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search term"
        
        Range("S24").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S25").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "Seach term"
        
        Range("S26").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S27").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " Search Term"
        
        Range("S28").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S29").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S34").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("S35").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        ' Input Lookup Values into Column V
        
        Range("V19").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search termf"
        
        Range("V20").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search termes"
        
        Range("V21").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search terms"
        
        Range("V22").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "  search termn"
        
        Range("V23").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search terme"
        
        Range("V24").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "  search termt"
        
        Range("V25").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search terms"
        
        Range("V26").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "  search terms"
        
        Range("V27").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "  search termg"
        
        Range("V28").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "  search termy"
        
        Range("V29").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = " search term"
        
        Range("V34").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        Range("V35").Select
        ActiveCell.Formula = "search term"
        
        
        'Input Column T Formulas
        
            Range("T19").Select
           
            ActiveCell.Formula2 = _
                "=CELL(""address"",INDEX(R18C13:R95C13,MATCH(RC[-1],R18C3:R95C3,0)))"
            Range("T19").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("T19:T36"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            
        ' Input Column U Formulas
        
            
            Range("U19").Select
            ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = "=CELL(""address"",OFFSET(INDIRECT(RC[-1]),-2,0))"
            Range("U19").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("U19:U36"), Type:=xlFillDefault
        
        ' Input Column W Formulas
        
            Range("W19").Select
            ActiveCell.Formula2R1C1 = _
                "=CELL(""address"",INDEX(R18C13:R95C13,MATCH(RC[-1],R18C3:R95C3,0)))"
            Range("W19").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("W19:W36"), Type:=xlFillDefault
           
        ' Input Column X Formulas
        
            Range("X19").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3],"":"",RC[-1])"
            Range("X19").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("X19:X36"), Type:=xlFillDefault
           
        ' Input Dark Box around Ranges and Formulas
        
        Range("S18:X37").Select
            Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .ColorIndex = 0
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .Weight = xlMedium
            End With
            Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
            Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
        
        ' Input Formulas into Columns N & O
        
        
            Range("N18").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-2]),"""",IFERROR(RC[-2]-RC[-1],RC[-1]))"
            Range("N18").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("N18:N260"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("N18:N260").Select
               
               Range("O18").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[-3]),"""",IFERROR(RC[-1]/RC[-3]*100,RC[-2]))"
            Range("O18").Select
            Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("O18:O260"), Type:=xlFillDefault
            Range("O18:O260").Select
        
            Range("L18:L260").Select
            Selection.Copy
        
            Range("N18:O260").Select
            Range("N260").Activate
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
        '
        'Inputs Column M Formulas
        
TSW:
        If IsError(Range("X19")) Then GoTo TDES
            
        Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Select
            On Error GoTo TDES
            Selection.Find(What:="search term", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
                :=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(INDIRECT(R19C24))"
            ActiveCell.Select
            
TDES:
        
        If IsError(Range("X20")) Then GoTo TOSC
        
         Columns("C:C").EntireColumn.Select
            On Error GoTo TOSC
            Selection.Find(What:=" search term", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn _
                :=xlFormulas2, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
                xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.Formula = "=SUM(INDIRECT(R20C24))"
            ActiveCell.Select
 TOSC
           
' here my code basically repeats 25 times querying a new generic search term each time, and inputting formulas appropriately. 

Next
```

If there is any way to loop this, I would be very happy to learn of it.

Comment: Your code is only looking at the WS that you are on. In order to look through other worksheets you have to Add `ws.` in front of the ranges you want make changes to. ie (`ws.Range("S19").Formula = "search term"`)